# Tkinter: tk.PanedWindow when placed into tkScrolledFrame - loosing contents or too stretched

Tags: python, tkinter

In order to display information contained in some sentences, after trying several options I found that PanedWindow solved my needs.

I build the PanedWindow this way:

```py
    def create_widgets(self):
        lbl_dir_eval = tk.Label(self, text="Information extracted from document" + self.docname.get(),
                                font=("Arial", 12))
        lbl_dir_eval.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # Create a widget to contain the sentences
        # a paned window is the best option for displaying one sentence per line
        width = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() // 1.6)
        height = round(self.winfo_screenheight() // 1.8)
        self.pan = tk.PanedWindow(self, width=width, height=height, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.pan.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        accept = tk.Button(self, text="Accept document")
        accept.grid(row=2, column=0)
        reject = tk.Button(self, text="Reject document")
        reject.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def add_sentence_display(self, sentence):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.pan)
        frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        for token in sentence['sentence']:
            if type(token) is tuple:
                label = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text=token[1])
                label.pack(side='left')
                content = tk.Label(label, text=token[0])
                content.pack()
            else:
                label = tk.Label(frame, text=token)
                label.pack(side='left')
        self.pan.add(frame, stretch="always")
```

And I get [contents overflowing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28su5.png). The sentences are too long and overflow to the right, and there are too many sentences that overflow to the bottom, and the two buttons (accept and reject) are out of the screen.

In order to correct this overflowing, I have put the PanedWindow into a ScrolledFrame this way:

```py
    def create_widgets(self):
        lbl_dir_eval = tk.Label(self, text="Information extracted from document" + self.docname.get(),
                                font=("Arial", 12))
        lbl_dir_eval.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # frame to contain extraction display
        # it needs scrollbars because contents overflow the widget
        width = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() // 1.6)
        height = round(self.winfo_screenheight() // 1.8)
        self.sf = tkscrolledframe.ScrolledFrame(self, width=width, height=height, scrollbars="both") # maybe , use_ttk=True)
        self.sf.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Create a widget to contain the sentences
        # a paned window is the best option for displaying one sentence per line
        self.pan = self.sf.display_widget(tk.PanedWindow)
        self.pan.configure(orient=tk.VERTICAL, width=width, height=height)

        accept = tk.Button(self, text="Accept document")
        accept.grid(row=2, column=0)
        reject = tk.Button(self, text="Reject document")
        reject.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def add_sentence_display(self, sentence):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.pan)
        frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        for token in sentence['sentence']:
            if type(token) is tuple:
                label = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text=token[1])
                label.pack(side='left')
                content = tk.Label(label, text=token[0])
                content.pack()
            else:
                label = tk.Label(frame, text=token)
                label.pack(side='left')
        self.pan.add(frame) # maybe , stretch="always")
```

But then either using stretch the contents go unreadable ([stretched unreadable contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5zrF.png)) or not using stretch contents are shown in a flash and then they disappear and only some remain visible ([most contents disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Cuv.png)).

I cannot find a way to show the contents in a readable way and displaying all of them. It seems many are getting removed for some reason I cannot understand.

---

As requested, adding a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkscrolledframe


class View(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        print("View init")
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.grid()
        self.parent = parent
        self.extraction = []
        self.docname = tk.StringVar(value="")

        self.create_widgets()
        print("View instantiated")

    def create_widgets(self):
        lbl_dir_eval = tk.Label(self, text="Information extracted from document" + self.docname.get(),
                                font=("Arial", 12))
        lbl_dir_eval.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # frame to contain extraction display
        # it needs scrollbars because contents overflow the widget
        width = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() // 1.6)
        height = round(self.winfo_screenheight() // 1.8)
        self.sf = tkscrolledframe.ScrolledFrame(self, width=width, height=height, scrollbars="both", use_ttk=True)
        self.sf.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Create a widget to contain the sentences
        # a paned window is the best option for displaying one sentence per line
        self.pan = self.sf.display_widget(tk.PanedWindow)
        self.pan.configure(orient=tk.VERTICAL, width=width, height=height)

        accept = tk.Button(self, text="Accept document")
        accept.grid(row=2, column=0)
        reject = tk.Button(self, text="Reject document")
        reject.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def add_sentence_display(self, sentence):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.pan)
        frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        print('sentence')
        for token in sentence['sentence']:
            if type(token) is tuple:
                label = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text=token[1])
                label.pack(side='left')
                content = tk.Label(label, text=token[0])
                content.pack()
            else:
                label = tk.Label(frame, text=token)
                label.pack(side='left')
        self.pan.add(frame) #, stretch="never")

    def run(self):
        print("Extractor running")


def main(window):
    view = View(window)
    view.run()
    return view


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("IRenE")
    width = round(window.winfo_screenwidth() // 1.5)
    height = round(window.winfo_screenheight() // 1.5)
    window.geometry(str(width) + 'x' + str(height))

    view = main(window)
    sentence = {'sentence': [' 3  Applied Energy 259 (2020) 114240  The first ', ('condenser', 'EQUIPMENT'), ' operates with water as a coolant ', ('at 20 ºC', 'DEGREE'), ', and the second one with ', ('methanol', 'COMPOUND'), ' at −20 ', ('ºC.', 'DEGREE'), ' The ', ('pyrolysis', 'PROCESS'), ' oil is captured in vessels at the bottom of the ', ('condensers', 'EQUIPMENT'), ', and uncondensed vapor goes through an impact separator (IP) and an electrostatic ', ('precipitator', 'EQUIPMENT'), ' (EP), which separate the remaining oil ', ('fraction', 'FRACTION'), ' from the gas.']}
    for i in range(100):
        view.add_sentence_display(sentence)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to create a complete [mcve] in a single block of code so we don't have to cut and paste and add additional code to make it work.

Comment: I thought it was an already reproducible example. The code is part of a BIG application with many classes. I will try...

Comment: Nothing calls the functions or creates the root window. The class definition is missing.

Comment: I have added a standalone class that can be directly run and shows the problem. I hope it is what you requested.

Comment: You are missing `self.pan.pack()` or `self.pan.grid()` or `self.pan.place()`. Also you need to add Bind the arrow keys and scroll wheel.

Comment: SOLVED: the PanedWindow doesn't increase height and width, it just tries to accommodate contents within it. I have set height and width to 10000 each and everything is shown ok. 
        self.pan = self.sf.display_widget(tk.PanedWindow)
        self.pan.configure(orient=tk.VERTICAL, width=10000, height=10000)